# Doubt in the derivation of Gauss's law in dielectrics

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, capacitance, gauss-law, dielectric

[image: Page 1]
[image: Page 2]
[image]

so in the 2nd page,when the dielectric material is introduced the gauss's law becomes  $$\oint _ { S } \vec { E } \cdot \vec { d S } = \frac { ( q - q _ { i } ) } { \epsilon _ { 0 } }$$.But my question is why the ${ \epsilon _ { 0 } }$is in the equation.Shouldn't it be  ${ \epsilon }(\varepsilon = k \varepsilon _ { 0 })$ ?And the formula becomes

$$\oint _ { S } \vec { E } \cdot \vec { d S } = \frac { ( q - q _ { i } ) } { k \varepsilon _ { 0 } }$$

Because

${ \epsilon _ { 0 } }$ is used when the medium is air or vacuum, but here the medium is dielectric near the gaussian surface, so ${ \epsilon }$  should be used instead of ${ \epsilon _ { 0 } }$ in the gauss's law here.

Comment: Did you get any answer to it, I have the same question right now.

Comment: Actually your question is an interesting one !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The book is correct, although this is not quite a general derivation since it derives Gauss' law for a specific structure, and assumes a linear and uniform dielectric.

Gauss' law in the form
$$ \oint\limits_S{\vec{E}·d\vec{S}} = \frac{q}{\epsilon_0}. $$
is *always* valid, dielectric or not. $q$ here is the total charge enclosed by $S$, including charges induced in dielectrics. The alternative form of Gauss' law, sometimes called the macroscopic form, is
$$ \oint\limits_S{\vec{D}·d\vec{S}} = q_f $$
where $\vec{D}$ is the electric flux density equal to $\epsilon \vec{E}$ in linear media, and $q_f$ is the *free* charge enclosed by $S$, not including induced charges. In a uniform linear medium, this equation can also be written as
$$ \oint\limits_S{\vec{E}·d\vec{S}} = \frac{q_f}{\epsilon} = \frac{q_f}{\kappa\epsilon_0}. $$